# Align a mic icon and text listening next to input field and button with the same width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input field and a button that says click me, also a mic icon and a span that is inside a div, and the span text is triggered when the icon is clicked, I want to align (span and mic icon) next to the input field, without changing the width of input field, so I want input field and button to have the same width, and the mic icon and text (id=action) next to the input field. How do I do that?

Without the mic and span, they have same width.

[image]

But with mic and span, the width of the text input field becomes ugly, I don't want that.

[image]

I removed many things, just to clarify to you what I mean, and for the code to understand easier, don't worry about the JS code, just when you click the mic icon, it triggers the span text.

```css
input {
  background-color: #dce1eb;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

button {
  background-color: #ac485a;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 30px auto;
  max-width: 320px;
}

#voice{
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div style="display: flex">
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="" id="input-field" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <img
          src="assets/microphone.png"
          id="voice"
          onclick="SpeechRecog()"
          alt=""
        />
        <span id="action"></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button id="add-button">Click Me</button>
  </div>

  <script src="index2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give the container enough padding-right, and then absolutely position the icon container in there ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution with `position: absolute`. All the necessary comments are included and changes are marked inside the codes.

```css
input {
    background-color: #dce1eb;
    border: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    /* added codes */
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* added codes */
}

button {
    background-color: #ac485a;
    border: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 30px auto;
    max-width: 320px;
}

#voice{
    width: 40px;
}

/* added code */
.input-container{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div style="display: flex; position: relative; align-items: center;"><!-- added code -->
        <div class="input-container">
          <input type="text" name="" placeholder="" id="input-field" />
        </div>

        <!-- Adjust the right property as required -->
        <div style="position: absolute; right: -90px; display: flex; align-items: center;"><!-- added code -->
          <img
            src="https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/microphone.png"
            id="voice"
            onclick="SpeechRecog()"
            alt="microphone"
          />
          <span id="action">action</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button id="add-button">Click Me</button>
    </div>

    <script src="index2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.

You can change your outer container `.container` to a `grid` with two rows and two columns. Put your two buttons in the left-hand column and the mic image in the top right cell. For example:

```
.container {
  margin: 30px auto;
  max-width: 320px;
/* grid CSS related attributes */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "aa ab"
    "ba bb";  
}

.aa {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-area: aa;
}

.ab {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-area: ab;
}

.ba {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-area: ba;
}

.bb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-area: bb;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a `table` with two rows and two columns to do the same thing. It is simpler to style but probably considered a bad practice, as we ought not use tables to do layouts.